# Legend Label Customizaton not working in Model Controller

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

Based on the following [implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/s8mywm33/15/), I could able to customize legend labels, it works when I put in my viewcontroller

```
series: [{
 field: "value",
 name :"#= group.items[0].fname || group.items[1].fname#" 
}],
```

However, when I put in my model view controller, then it does not work.

```
chart.setDataSource(theDataSource);
chart.options.series.name = "#= group.items[0].fname || group.items[1].fname#"
chart.refresh();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you update the options property, you need to call refresh() when you are done (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#fields-options):

```
chart.refresh();
```

You could also try using the setOptions method (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#methods-setOptions):

```
var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
chart.setOptions({ 
    series: [{
        field: "value",
        name :"#= group.items[0].fname || group.items[1].fname#" 
    }] 
});
```

The following approach should work,

change the following line of code

```
chart.options.series.name = "#= group.items[0].fname || group.items[1].fname#"
```

to

```
chart.options.series[0].name = "#= group.items[0].fname || group.items[1].fname#";
```

Comment: Thanks ezanker, I had  `chart.refresh();` at right after `chart.options.series.name ` but it does not show `fname`. By the way what if I have around 10 of bar charts. How should I handle `group.items[0].fname, .........., group.items[10].fname,` I have upvoted your effort.

Comment: @casillas, you could also try chart.redraw();.  if you have 10 categories, the series name template may not be the best way to go. Perhaps you could make the fname of all same items for a category the same, that way the series name could be group.items[0].fname regardless of whether the value is 0 or not.